# Find out if current Chrome tab is muted in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, volume

Google Chrome has a feature to mute a tab.

Is there a way to use JavaScript to discover whether the tab your page is in has been silenced in this way?

Could be a neat way to also mute any notifications or incoming chat messages.

Comment: Neat, but highly annoying when you really just wanted to mute the sounds and nothing else. Anyway, I don't think there is a way to read the mute status.

Comment: @Juhana Clearly the feature would be defined in such a way that the user knew what it would do. Mute is mute though - don't notify of anything incoming. It would just be nice, but I'm surprised that Google haven't even made this available even through a proprietary method.